# hibernate with mysql to MongoDB

Tags: spring, mongodb, hibernate, spring-data-mongodb, hibernate-ogm

Hi I have planned to migrate from Hibernate with MySQL to MongoDb

Does any one know eigther Hibernate OGM is good or Spring data or any think else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring Data MongoDB is certainly a very powerful framework to use and one, if you're comfortable with ORM-like tools, makes a lot of sense.  The `MongoRepository` api takes care of all the CRUD boiler plate and the `findBy...` methods and query helpers reduce a *lot* of work.  Definitely worth looking at.

have a look at [the docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/mongodb/docs/1.2.3.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/) for some nice examples and github as well.

Answer (score 1):

Look at MongoJack
http://mongojack.org/

I found it a lot faster and easier to use than Spring Data.